# SPD Workflows (No Coding) are excruciatingly slow on SP 2013, But, Fast on SP2010 - How to improve?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, performance

We have SharePoint 2013 environment enterprise edition, and a deployed Workflow Manager server. All our servers have very powerful resources (CPUs & RAMs)

Our SPD Workflows (No Coding) are excruciatingly slow and it takes up to 10 minutes or more to process normal operations and change the status from a step to another.

Our old SharePoint 2010 environment works smoothly with much less resources (CPUs & RAMs), and the exact same SPD Workflows (100% identical) work very smoothly and super fast where it takes a few seconds.

What is wrong with my environment? How can I improve the performance of our SPD Workflows onto our SharePoint 2013 environment?

I have read these articles:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd441390(v=office.12).aspx

and I applied its stsadm-commands:

- Increase Throttle Size:

  stsadm -o setproperty -pn workflow-eventdelivery-throttle -pv "25"
- Increase Batch Size:

  stsadm -o setproperty -pn workitem-eventdelivery-batchsize -pv "125"
- Time Out:

  stsadm -o setproperty -pn workflow-eventdelivery-timeout -pv "10"
- Workflow Timer Interval:

  stsadm -o setproperty -pn job-workflow -pv "Every 10 minutes between 0 and 30" -url http://webapplication:port

Still the performance is extremely poor

Could you help me out to resolve this performance issue? - Please !

Comment: Hi did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of troubleshooting the root cause of your performance issues, can you provide any potential finding and analysis produced from the [event viewer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/factors-affecting-workflow-performance-in-sharepoint/)? If you go to the Event Viewer > Application and Service Logs > Microsoft-Workflow, then right-click and select View > Show Analytics and Debug Logs. This should provide you some information regarding the source of your performance issues.

Secondarily, if you have access to the SharePoint 2013 Database, you can directly query for errors that have occurred during workflow execution: the table "DebugTraces" in the Workflow Instance Management Database.

Lastly, in terms of suggestions, I would ensure Workflow Manager, has the latest [cumulative updates](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42036) installed.